# Passing a Python string into JSON payload

Tags: python, json, variables, payload

I have this in my code:

```
targetTemp = 17
...
payload = "{\n    \"nodes\": [{\n        \"attributes\": {\n            \"targetHeatTemperature\": {\n                \"targetValue\": '+ targetTemp +',\n            }\n        }\n    }]\n}"
```

I've tried a few things I've found online but nothing seems to work.  If I replace '+ targetTemp +', with, say, 18 then it does what I want.

I've tried just with single quotes and no plus signs, just the variable name, without the comma at the end.  I'm just stumbling round in the dark, really.

Comment: `json.dumps` is probably what you want to use instead of manually building json strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'+ targetTemp +'` within the outermost double quotes isn't doing string concatenation. It's literally putting that text.

You should be using `"+ targetTemp +"`

However, building an actual dictionary, and using `json.dumps` will be less error-prone

Comment: That got me there after a fashion.  I actually get the value from a MySQL table so it's targetTemp = data[0].  I then had to add targetTemp=str(targetTemp) as I was getting a server error.  Thank you though, this got me where I want to be

Answer (score 9):

The reason your string isn't working is because you used double quotes `"` for the string instead of single quotes `'`. Since json format requires double quotes, you only should be using double quotes inside the string itself and then use the single quotes to denote the start/end of a string. (That way you don't need to keep using those `\"` unnecessarily.
Also, `.format()` can help with putting variables inside strings to make them easier.

This should fix your json string:

```
targetTemp = 17

payload = '{\n    "nodes": [{\n        "attributes": {\n            "targetHeatTemperature": {\n                "targetValue": {},\n            }\n        }\n    }]\n}'.format(targetTemp)
```

However, using the `json` module makes things a lot easier because it allows you to pass in a python dictionary which can be converted from/to a json string.

Example using the `json` package:

```
import json

targetTemp = 17

payload = {
    "nodes": [{
        "attributes": {
            "targetHeatTemperature": {
                "targetValue": targetTemp
            }
        }
    }]
}

payload_json = json.dumps(payload)  # Convert dict to json string
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `payload` is awfully complex, you don't need to enclose it in quotes since it can be treated as a `dict`, also your `targetTemp` is being treated as a string this is why you don't see the actual value.

You may need to look into [Python string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) for simplicity.

This would do what you want,

```
import json

targetTemp = 17
payload = {
    "nodes": [{
        "attributes": {
            "targetHeatTemperature": {
                "targetValue": targetTemp
            }
        }
    }]
}

print(json.dumps(payload))

# output,
{"nodes": [{"attributes": {"targetHeatTemperature": {"targetValue": 17}}}]}
```

Please note that you can also use [JSON Validators](https://jsonlint.com/) to make sure your json object is indeed in a correct format.(that's what I used to format your provided `JSON`)

Comment: Why format instead of put the value directly? Or even `str(targetTemp)`?

Comment: I use Postman to get my API call right and then export it from there.  This is my first Python/Flask/JSON project.  I might have bitten off more than I can chew but most things are working.

Comment: make sense @AndyJ, hope my answer helped you

Answer (score 2):

Let's shorten that code down a bit.

```
payload = "{...\"targetValue\": '+ targetTemp +'...}"
```

See the problem now?  `payload` is delimited with double quotes, so in order to exit, append to, and "re-enter" the string, you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
payload = "{...\"targetValue\": "+ targetTemp +"...}"
```

Alternatively, the far more robust and less tedious solution would be to build up `payload` as a `dict` of Python structures containing `targetTemp` as a normal value, and *then* after that serialize it with `json.dumps`:

```
payload_obj = {
    "nodes": [{
         "attributes": {
             "targetHeatTemperature": {
                 "targetValue": targetTemp,
             }
         }
    }]
}

payload = json.dumps(payload_obj)
```